# Rotate Video Metadata - ffmpeg vs ExifTool

Tags: ffmpeg

I created an `ffmpeg` script to rotate -90 some videos that I record on my Sony A7iii, with the camera vertically, this makes these videos display correctly.

the script is this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=-90 output.mp4
```

The issue is that for some reason all the output files are having variations of 2 frames, which causes me problems when I use these files as `Proxy` in Premiere Pro.

For example, if the original file has a `Media Duration` (in Premiere Pro) of `00:00:32:12`, the output file for some reason will have a `Media Duration` of `00:00:32:10`.

Another very curious point is that the file generated by `ffmpeg` always has a size variation, whereas the file generated by ExifTool has no variation at all...

**ExifTool**

Using this `ExifTool` command I can do the same conversion and I don't have this frame shifting problem:

```
exiftool -m -P -overwrite_original -api LargeFileSupport=1 -rotation=90 movie.mp4
```

But I would still like to be able to get the proper result using `ffmpeg`, because doing the work through `ffmpeg` would make my workflow easier.

Any idea why the problem is occurring?

#### Edit

I still haven't managed to get it to work through FFMPEG, does anyone have any ideas?